# Matlab code to extract ROI from hand image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working on matlab code which should be used to process hand image, I need to segment object(hand) from background, and I used threshold to do that, the next step is to extract specific patch from the segmented object(hand) I see it is possible to do it manually using imellipse or imfreehand, but actually I want to do it automatically for 100 images. 
can you please help me about this. is there code that may help to select patch with specific size from hand for further processing, and after selecting the required patch how to remove other part and save the new result?

[image: image size is 240*320 grayscale as shown]

Code, here I show the usage of imrect but it give me the same selecting manually and I do not know how to proceed to save only the area I selected ?

```
x = imread ('0001hv1.bmp');    
b = im2double(x);

thresh_level = graythresh(b);
c = b > thresh_level;    
imshow(c);

d = im2double(c);    
d = im2double(c).*b;

imshow(d , []);

figure, imshow(d);

h = imrect(gca, [10 10 100 100]);

addNewPositionCallback(h,@(p) title(mat2str(p,3)));

fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('imrect',get(gca,'XLim'),get(gca,'YLim'));

setPositionConstraintFcn(h,fcn);
```

Comment: I was wondering the exact same thing @Jigg. For the OP: Can you show the code you have written so far and point where is your problem? Have you tried using imfreehand and it does not work or you have not tried it yet?

Comment: Yes I tried imfreehand and the problem is that each time I need to process image I need to select patch manually, the code I have till know is only segment the image and it works..     x = imread ('0001hv1.bmp');
b = im2double(x);
 thresh_level = graythresh(b);
 c = b > thresh_level;
 imshow(c);
Trial>> d = im2double(c);
d = im2double(c).*b;imshow(d , []);

Comment: ok please add this code in your question and format it using the curly braces {} so that it's much easier to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it working correctly.  Once you threshold your image, you can determine the bounding box of the hand by finding the minimum and maximum row and column values, which correspond to the top left and bottom right of your hand.  As such, all you need to do is determine where the pixels are white, then find the minimum and maximum row and column values.

I'll use a bit of your code, but I'll insert what I would do at the end.  Take note that I cropped out the top and bottom 10 pixels, as well as the left and right 10 pixels because there seems to be some sort of non-uniform border that appears when you're thresholding your image:

```
x = rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmnLv.jpg')); %// Read in your image from StackOverflow
x = im2double(x(10:end-10,10:end-10)); %// Crop out a 10 pixel border and convert to [0,1]
thresh_level = graythresh(x); %// Threshold the image
c = x > thresh_level;

%// NEW Code
%//----------
%//Find minimum spanning bounding box
[rows,cols] = find(c);
top_left_x = min(cols(:));
top_left_y = min(rows(:));
bottom_right_x = max(cols(:));
bottom_right_y = max(rows(:));

%//Determine width of bounding box
width = bottom_right_x - top_left_x + 1;
height = bottom_right_y - top_left_y + 1;

%// Draw rectangle onto image
imshow(x);
h = imrect(gca, [top_left_x top_left_y width height]);
%// End NEW Code
%// -----------

%// From your code... don't know what this is doing actually...
addNewPositionCallback(h,@(p) title(mat2str(p,3)));    
fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('imrect',get(gca,'XLim'),get(gca,'YLim'));    
setPositionConstraintFcn(h,fcn);
```

Note that [`imrect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrect.html) requires a handle to the figure you want to draw the rectangle onto, which in your case is the original hand you want to display to the user.  It also requires a four element array which denotes the rectangle, such that it follows the following convention:

```
[top_left_x top_left_y width height]
```

`top_left_x` and `top_left_y` are the column and row location of the top left corner of the rectangle, while `width` and `height` are the width and height of this rectangle.  As such, this exactly corresponds to the bounding box of your palm.

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help, I have some questions: what is the point from the first line rgb2gray, cos all images are in gray scale ?    another thing: what I am looking for is the hand only because it will be used later for further processing, my code has almost similar result to your code and it was criticised because there is no consistency while selecting the same patch from all images ? I found this function 'bwtraceboundary' any idea if it is suitable to detect the boundary of hand only?

Comment: @user3485941 - (1) I used `rgb2gray` because when you read in the image from StackOverflow, it is in colour... even if it's grayscale, so I had to convert using `rgb2gray`. (2) I don't expect that there is consistency between multiple images as the hand placement may be different.  I don't see what you mean by that.  `bwtraceboundary` could work, but this will trace over the object.  I'm not quite sure what application you want in the end.

Comment: :) what is my application: is a software that use algorithm which is used to extract features from texture, hand here is the texture that I am going to apply the algorithm on it. about the hand placement, actually all images are captured under same condition and there is designed
hand attachment frame for constraining the person’s hand; so to some extent I can ensure that the position of hand during capturing is not issue!

Comment: @user3485941 - OK, so how specifically do you want to segment the hand? Do you want a minimum spanning bounding box, or do you want to trace over the perimeter of the hand?

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience, actually according to what I have tried using box to extract ROI is practical and will help in next step where I need to select pixels and do intensity comparison, but my teacher proposed using boundary tracking algorithm, I did some search and try implementing methods I found but it does not work. you can refer ( A method for hand vein recognition based on Curvelet Transform phase feature). [http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/icp.jsp?arnumber=6199537]  link for whole method and figures. thank you.

Comment: @user3485941 - That's outside the scope of StackOverflow.  You are essentially asking me to help you implement an entire method.  I can help you, but that will require that you hire me as a Codementor :) http://www.codementor.io/rayryeng - If you're interested and want to hire me, then we can talk.  If you don't, then the buck stops here.  Good luck!